# How much fuel is necessary for 2nd stage of Falcon 9 rocket to land?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, fuel, reuse, upper-stage

What is the fuel mass nedeed for the 2nd stage of Falcon 9 rocket to land, how much compared with its total fuel mass that it has? Or how much delta-v is necessary? Would it be able for Falcon 9 to send any payload into orbit if they would try to land the 2nd stage, if yes how much?

Comment: I don't think this is answerable at present. The existing second stage design can't land at all, and we don't yet have the necessary details about SpaceX's plans for second stage recovery. It's certain they'll be able to deliver some payload to LEO with a recoverable second stage (otherwise why bother?) but beyond that we don't know.

Comment: It is difficult to calculate delta-v necessary for the landing since it needs modifications. For sure that currently can't land since should have an heatshield and some landing legs, if not some other engines as supercdraco thrusters. What about any simulation programs, including only the mass of hypothetical heatshield and landing legs and using only its Mvac engine for landing? Not necessary to be 100% accurate but just to have as an idea how much delta-v is needed or the % of total fuel mass.